# Given a typical Rails 3 environment, why am I unable to execute any tests?

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm working on writing simple unit tests for a Rails 3 project, but I'm unable to actually execute any tests.

Case in point, attempting to run the test auto-generated by Rails fails:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Replace this with your real tests.
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

Results in the following error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
test_helper (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from user_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Commenting out the require 'test_helper' line and attempting to run the test results in this error:

```
user_test.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Object::ActiveSupport (NameError)
```

The action pack gems appear to be properly installed and up to date:

```
actionmailer (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
actionpack (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
activeresource (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.3, 2.3.5)
```

Ruby is at 1.9.2p0 and Rails is at 3.0.3.

The sample dump of my test directory is as follows:

```
/fixtures
/functional
/integration
/performance
/unit
-- /helpers
   -- user_helper_test.rb
-- user_test.rb
test_helper.rb
```

I've never seen this problem before - I've run the typical rake tasks for preparing the test environment. I have nothing out of the ordinary in my application or environment configuration files, nor have I installed any unusual gems that would interfere with the test environment.

**Edit March 9th**

[Xavier Holt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589985/xavier-holt)'s suggestion, explicitly specifying the path to the test_helper worked; however, this revealed an issue with ActiveSupport.

Now when I attempt to run the test, I receive the following error message (as also listed above):

```
user_test.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Object::ActiveSupport (NameError)
```

But as you can see above, Action Pack is all installed and update to date.

**Edit March 13th**

When attempting to run tests using `rake test:units` the following stack trace is dumped to the console:

```
test/unit/bookmark_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Objec
t::ActiveSupport (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
```

So looking into the file listed above, I see the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Load the test files from the command line.

ARGV.each { |f| load f unless f =~ /^-/  }
```

To my knowledge, everything looks as expected.

Comment: Could you list the contents of your `test` directory? No need to list *every* unit test, etc, just the general overview (specifically where `test_helper.rb` is).

Comment: My Rails mentor had me change all the `require 'test_helper'` lines in my tests to `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'`.  While this was to solve a different problem (and yes, it's ugly as hell), I suspect it might work for you.

Comment: That worked, but ended up revealing another issue with ActiveSupport. Updating the question.

Comment: How are you actually executing the tests? `rake test` or something else?

Comment: @Dan Right now, I'm just trying to run a single test '> ruby test/unit/user_test.rb'

Comment: Your test_helper.rb is still not being loaded. That is why you see the same error message that you saw when you commented out the require 'test_helper' line.

Comment: @Austin Thanks for the heads up. This had me go back through @Ryan's answer and I traced the issue to the test_helper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `test/test_helper` file should have been created when you generated the application. It contains this valuable content:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

The second line here is the most important: it requires the `config/environment.rb` file at the root of your application, which in turn requires a lot of other things, including the valuable (I like that word today, ok?) `ActiveSupport` constant.

When you generate a controller, model or scaffold it'll also generate tests for those. I just ran `rails g scaffold ticket` in my app and it generated `test/unit/ticket_test.rb` which contains this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TicketTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Replace this with your real tests.
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

The first line of this file will require the `test/test_helper.rb` file that we jut saw. This will load `ActiveSupport` and the `TestCase` class within it, thereby making this test feasible. Everything else just flows on from there.

With all that explanation out of the way (even though it's something that you already know),  I'm placing a large wager on it's something that's masscaring your `LOAD_PATH`, causing the `test` directory to be removed from it.

What's really unusual is that when you do specify the full path to the `test/test_helper.rb` you're saying it loads it, but `ActiveSupport` is still undefined. Well, that should be loaded as-per the description above. Is it actually loading `config/environment.rb`? Can you put something such as:

```
puts "LOADING CONFIG/ENVIRONMENT.RB"
```

At the top of your `config/environment.rb` file and then run the tests again? It should be output. Very unusual.

<s>Continuing on the thread about `LOAD_PATH`... Got a dirty little secret you're not telling us about?</s>

Actually, Dan Cheail makes a good point. You could be running the tests using `ruby test/unit/ticket_test.rb` in which case `test_helper` wouldn't be available, but still that still doesn't explain why when you specify the full path you're still getting an undefined constant `ActiveSupport`.

If you want to run a single test you should be doing this:

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/ticket_test.rb
```

That `-I` option there adds the `test` directory to the load path, meaning the `test_helper` file will be available through a straight `require 'test_helper'`. If it still errors after this, I reckon your `test/test_helper.rb` is either empty or broken.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Everything that you've outlined here is in place with the exception of specifying the print out at the top of environment.rb - it actually doesn't print. I *am* running tests using '> ruby test/unit/user_test.rb' as that's how I've always been running tests (since the early versions of Rails). Is Rake the preferred way even for single files?

Comment: Tom: yes you should be using `rake` to run them. If you want to run a single one I would recommend running this command `ruby -Itest test/unit/ticket_test.rb`. I'll update the answer with an explanation.

Comment: I updated my comment on @Dan's answer. When I attempt to run ruby -Itest, I still receive the uninitialized constant exception for ActiveSupport.

Comment: The problem ended up being a minor oversight in my part. The test_helper.rb file was botched such that the second line (with the File.expand_path call) did not include the proper path to environment. Updating that path fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the post here, but I am unable to comment on questions yet.

what environment are you running, Win (has an issue with a .gemspec file) Linux, Mac?

Are you using RVM?

Test-Unit is installed by default with Rails, if you installed the gem Test-Unit you will get a conflict between the 2. try uninstalling the gem and your tests should start working.

If running on windows I would gem uninstall "autotest", then navigate to the following dir

```
   drive:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\specifications
```

In here you will find .gemspec files. Ensure that you dont have 2 autotest.gemspec files or any, for that matter. if so remove(delete) them, then download and gem install the autotest gem again. Grab the latest by using version switch.

You should be able to run your autotests. I did come across this once before, so to fix I simply removed the view and helper test files and wrote everything in the standard test file. Other than that I know running on windows autotest had issues, because of the ruby installer and bundler not clearing out things correctly and forgetting files.

I will find the link for you, to better explain.

Comment: Running on Windows and all gems are typical with a Rails 3 installation. Haven't added any additional testing tools.

Comment: @Tom have updated the answer for you, regarding a dir to look at.

Comment: No autotest.gemspec files were located in /specifications. The only file similar to that is .old.rake.gemspec.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is the way you're executing tests. Simply calling `ruby test/unit/user_test.rb` doesn't set up the load path, which explains the problems you've been having.

`rake test:units` is what you want and should work straight away.

Comment: Unfortunately, rake test:units is still resulting in a stack trace. The first line contains: test/unit/user_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::ActiveSupport (NameError)